# create a tiled background image to a control in windows phone 7 silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

this is probably simple but i'm spinning my wheels on it.

i have a small 16x16 image that i want to tile to fill the background of my app.  (LayoutRoot grid control in this case)

ImageBrush gives option to stretch it, but no option to tile it.

i'm sure it's possible to do this?

```
<Grid.Background>
  <ImageBrush ImageSource="/myApp;component/dark_cf6.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
</Grid.Background>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a pixel shader, have a look at http://blog.shazzam-tool.com/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901594(v=vs.95).aspx

I have used this method for other purposes before but there is a tiled image effect.

Comment: thanks but it appears that wp7 does not support any effects.  it did in one of the earlier CTPs but removed at beta, and even then not custom shaders.

Answer (score -1):

WPF supports using a [VisualBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush.aspx) to create tiled backgrounds. WP7 *should* support this as well:

```
<Grid.Background>
   <ImageBrush ImageSource="/myApp;component/dark_cf6.png" 
               TileMode="Tile" 
               ViewportUnits="Absolute" 
               Viewport="0,0,16,16" />
</Grid.Background>
```

The [ViewPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.viewport.aspx) property is the key that will set up the correct tiling.

Comment: thanks for the response.  it appears that VisualBrush is not supported in WP7, and there is no TileMode, Viewport, etc. in ImageBrush (WP7).  i do find this curious as this is pretty standard functionality that one would expect to be able to do.

Comment: Wow. I just fired up the wp7 emulator and indeed TileMode/Viewport is not supported. I suspect that tiled backgrounds are not supported since the screen resolution is standardized and you can just create a single image with the tiled effect. That's just my wild guess, though.